# How would I associate an IP address with switch name in drop down menu

Tags: powershell, variables, drop-down-menu

I'm not entirely sure how to word this so bare with me. The orginization i work for is taking away a license for a software we use to connect to our network switches using a basic SSH connection. Just using PowerShell i know this command works for us. `ssh username@IP_of_Switch` now comes the fun part.

I want to make a GUI for our techs so they just have to select the switch name and not have to know every IP of all 100+ switches. I know for a drop down box it would look like this

```
$DropDownBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDownBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,50)
$DropDownBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,20)
$DropDownBox.DropDownHeight = 200
$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownBox)
$swList=@("1D","3D","3F","6E","Laundry","Chapel")
foreach ($sws in $swList) {$DropDownBox.Items.Add($sw)} #end foreach
```

What i want to do is have those Names be associated with their respective IP some how. AND HAVE A BUTTON TO CONNECT THEM TO SELECTED SWITCHI have a slight idea that i may need to have a txt file with the IP's. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where will the IP addresses come from?

Comment: Well as of right now they are listed in a txt file stored on 'C:\Users\myname\Desktop'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `ComboBox` is inherited from `ListControl`
2. You should provide Objects to ListItems. Each object should contain at least 2 properties: `displayName` and `value` ( you can change names of properties how you want ).
3. You need to set `ComboBox`'s properties `DisplayMember` to name of property should be displayed.

Example:

In `$FormEvent_Load` scriptblock, we add items to ComboBox. Those items are objects with (at least) 2 properties - Name and Address. There we also set `DisplayMember` property of ComboBox to let it know, which property should be displayed in UI.

In `$CBEvent_SelectedIndexChanged` scriptblock, we get `SelectedItem` property from ComboiBox. `SelectedItem` contains original object we passed to `ComboBox.Items.Add`. There is Address field as you see, which can be used.

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

$FormEvent_Load = {
    $combobox1.DisplayMember = 'Name'
    $combobox1.Items.Add(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Name' = 'Switch1'
            'Address' = [ipaddress]::Parse('1.1.1.1')
        })
    $combobox1.Items.Add(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Name' = 'Switch2'
            'Address' = [ipaddress]::Parse('2.12.21.22')
        })
}

$CBEvent_SelectedIndexChanged = {
    $label1.Text = $combobox1.SelectedItem.Address.ToString()
}

$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 292
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 266
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 83
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 199
$label1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label1.Text = 'Select IP'
$form1.Controls.Add($label1)
$form1.Controls.Add($combobox1)
$form1.add_Load($FormEvent_Load)
$ComboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged($CBEvent_SelectedIndexChanged)
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
```

Comment: Learning so much from this one "problem" looks like ill have it working in no time. just gotta do the manual work of plugging in my info. Thanks A LOT ill end up using a little bit of both answers.

Comment: Got it working with a button to connect the user to the Switch... just need to add a textbox for them to input their username. Thank you to everyone that helped me with this.. when im completely done with the script ill post it (minus personal info)

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example but it does work. I used a simple csv file to hold the switch IP Addresses. I edited an answer for the majority of this script so I will give credit for that [Powershell default dropdown value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25508087/6158454)

**CSV File**

```
1D,127.0.0.1
3D,127.0.0.2
3F,127.0.0.3
6E,127.0.0.4
Laundry,127.0.0.5
Chapel,127.0.0.6
```

**Script**

```
########################

# Edit This item to change the DropDown Values
$switchesFilePath = "C:\temp\switches.csv"

$switches = ConvertFrom-Csv (Get-Content -Path $switchesFilePath)

# This Function Returns the Selected Value and Closes the Form

function Return-DropDown {
 $script:Choice = $DropDown.SelectedItem
 Write-Host "The selected switch is $($script:Choice.Name) and it's IP is $($script:Choice.IPAddress)"
 Write-Host "The ssh command would be ---- ssh username@$($script:Choice.IPAddress)"
 $Form.Close()
}

function selectSwitch{
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")


    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

    $Form.width = 300
    $Form.height = 150
    $Form.Text = ”DropDown”

    $DropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $DropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,10)
    $DropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)
    $DropDown.SelectedItem = $DropDown.Items[0]
    $DropDown.DisplayMember = 'Name'
    [void] $DropDown.Items.AddRange($switches)

    $Form.Controls.Add($DropDown)

    $DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $DropDownLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) 
    $DropDownLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
    $DropDownLabel.Text = "Select a network switch"
    $Form.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel)

    $Button = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
    $Button.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
    $Button.Text = "Connect to a switch"
    $Button.Add_Click({Return-DropDown})
    $form.Controls.Add($Button)

    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
    [void] $Form.ShowDialog()


    return $script:choice
}

$switch = selectSwitch
```

Comment: This worked Perfectly! Makes sense to use a CSV, seems i was on the right track. Thank you again for your excellent answer.

Comment: You may want to take a look at @filimonic's answer. My answer and that answer could be combined to make an easier approach to this. Just using the `$switches` object and a `foreach loop` to populate the dropdown might make it better for you.

Comment: I actually just updated it to use the `$switches` object to fill the dropdown.